# Object accessing and loading

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a Java int[][][] object in a separate class.

The first dimension of the array has about 1000 elements, but I only need to access one at a time.

My question is: If I want to access only one element at a time, like this:

```
int[][] some2DInt = SomeClass.some3DInt[5];
```

Would this be effective? I mean, would Java load the entire 1000 elements or just the one I really want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no loading here. `int[][]` is an address so when you do something like :

```
int[][] some2DInt = SomeClass.some3DInt[5];
```

You just assign to `some2DInt` the address of the fifth 2 dimensional array in memory. So no copying or "loading" is done.

The loading (which is actually memory allocation) is done when you initialize your 3 dimensional array using the `new` operator. (or if you statically initialize this array which might be a cumbersome task especially with 1000 2d arrays)

Comment: If my some2DInt is actually pointing to my some3DInt, and the first one actually just points to the address somewhere in the other array, when I modify my 2D array, wouldn't I actually be modifying my 3D array (which is supposed to be static)?

Comment: Do not forget you are dealing with pointers, not values. So yes, a change in your 2d dimensional array will also show in the 3D array as the 2d dimensional array is part of the memory space for the  3D array